# PHP image resize isn't working

Tags: php

I found the following script from PHP site to half the size of the image. I use the database to fetch the link of the image. Other things are working correctly which means there isn't any kind of error anywhere except this one.

```
echo "<img src='".// File and new size
$filename = '$row["image"]';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
"'>"
```

**Error:**
The whole page is destroyed and there is a broken link of an image.
Hope you guys will help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after you drop those lines:

```
echo "<img src='".// File and new size

"'>"
```

`header` does it for you, informs that there is jpg coming, no need to echo image tag.

The other solution is to remove this line:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

And create new file, then use it as a source of an image:

```
// Output
$new_filename = 'new_image.jpg';
imagejpeg($thumb,$new_filename);//saves new image to a file, instead of outputting it to the screen
echo "<img src='$new_filename'>";
```

Comment: `header` is removed and other page is working but the image is broken. I don't want to save image as file because it will take size. If I have to use second method, is there a way to delete that created file as tab is closed?

Comment: you can delete it with cronjob, or whatever other way you use to garbage collect after session ends. Also remember not to output any characters before calling `header` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it works

```
<?php

$filename = '$row["image"]';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
 $newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output

echo "<img src='".imagejpeg($thumb)."'>";
?>
```